# Read a file character by character and store its character into 2D array OCaML

Tags: ocaml, ml

I have some test files of this format. (N rows, M columns 
where `4 <= N,M <= 1000` - the number of each is not given)

```
S..........XX..
.XXXXXXX.X.XX.X
.X.....W.X..X.X
...XXXWWWWX...X
XXX...X.XXXXXXX
EW..X..........
```

and I need to read each file character by character and store every character(ignoring newline characters) into a 2D array.
The array is initialized as follows

```
let n = 1000
let m = 1000
let grid = Array.init n (fun i -> Array.make_matrix m 2 'X')
```

I have no idea on how can I do that, I'm confused with string and scanf modules.

Answer (score 3):

I won't do it for you but here are some useful functions you could use :

```
val open_in : string -> in_channel
```

> Open the named file for reading, and return a new input channel on that file, positioned at the beginning of the file.

Then you can create a loop (with a recursive function, for example), in which you will read each line of your input file :

```
val input_line : in_channel -> string
```

> Read characters from the given input channel, until a newline character is encountered. Return the string of all characters read, without the newline character at the end. Raise End_of_file if the end of the file is reached at the beginning of line.

As you can see, an `End_of_file` exception will be raised once you reached the end of the file so a skeleton of your program would be

```
let file_to_list filename = 
  let file = open_in filename in
  let rec fill_list acc =
    try
      let line = input_line file in ...
      (* here you should fill the list *)
    with End_of_file -> acc
  in fill_list []
```

Once you'll get this list, you'll have the number of lines (length of the list) and the size of a line (length of the line) and you'll be able to fill your array (and initialize it with the proper values).

Another useful thing is to get the `n`th character of a string `s` just write `s.[n]`.

Comment: thnx! I thought I could skip inserting the lines into the list

Comment: Well, you can by using `read_char` instead of `read_line` but I'll let you find how. This function can be found in the Pervasives module (go browse the Internet for this ;-))